# Combing search results to use UNION or is there some other method

Tags: mysql

I have the following statement:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM wp_bibliography x
  JOIN wp_term_relationships y
    ON y.object_id = x.post_id 
WHERE y.term_taxonomy_id = 106
```

I need to return results from wp_bibliography where term_taxonomy_id could be a single number as above or multiple, i.e return rows where term_taxonomy_id could be 106 and 108.

Should I be using a UNION for this? Obviously I need to remove any duplicates.

I have tried to use an IN('106','108') however this causes duplication.

I can't use an AND because then the join won't work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you really code `IN('108','108')` or did you code `IN('106','108')`

Comment: And as they are numbers `IN(106,108)` would be better

Comment: 'Obviously I need to remove any duplicates' - not obvious to me, do you mean you only want 1 random row where the condition is met?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ... WHERE term_taxonomy_Id IN (106, 108)`?  Or something else?

Comment: As SQL is designed around [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) it's not that obviously to remove duplicates.. Also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `DISTINCT *`? Are you feeling OK?

Comment: RiggsFolly - why did you change my code in my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess, you're probably after something like this:

```
SELECT c.olumns
     , y.ou
     , a.ctually
     , w.ant 
  FROM wp_bibliography x
  JOIN wp_term_relationships y
    ON y.object_id = x.post_id 
 WHERE y.term_taxonomy_id IN(106,108)
 GROUP
    BY s.omething
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 -- WHERE '2 is the number of arguments in IN()
```

Comment: *"At a guess, you're probably after something like this:"* Most likely but you might want to do `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT y.term_taxonomy_id) = 2` instead

Comment: @timbiegeleisen it's an oxymoron, that's all.

Comment: So you would use the method above to create say a multi select results filter?

Comment: I don't know what a multi select results filter is.

Comment: Oh it's number of check boxes that you select to filter a set of results, so in this example 106 and 108 represent two different choices. Does that make sense?

Comment: OK - unless it was a very large data set, I'd probably just return the entire result, and handle any further filtering in application code. But yeah, for larger data sets, this might be what I'd do - but I'm operating at the edge of my knowledge base.